# How do I remove an old SQL Server 2008 Express Database Instance

Tags: sql-server-2008, database, database-restore

I am trying to restore a database over the existing one. This worked fine in the past, until all of a sudden, it doesnt.

I have clearly, in the past, attached the same database file under a different name and it now thinks that restoring a database over the current instance will overwrite the other instance as well hence giving me the following error:

```
Failed to restore database: The file 'E:\database\db.mdf' cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database 'ABC'.
File 'db' cannot be restored to 'E:\database\db.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.

The file 'E:\database\db_log.ldf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'ABC'.
File 'db_log' cannot be restored to 'E:\database\db_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
```

The big question: How do you delete references to the old database? How do you find what previous database instances were used even?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the conflicting files into a different directory/deleting them.  The operation is basically being told to overwrite files that it sees to be there with something different.  I had a similar problem on a test environment and discovered either deleting the conflicting files/moving them worked perfectly.

Also, have you tried to use the `WITH REPLACE` option under the restoration menu?  I'm not entirely sure this works for an instance named differently, but with a same name it will overwrite it perfectly fine.